# c# - Streamwriter Class

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Iam trying to write a `List<string>` to a file with the `StreamWriter`class.
When iam passing the args (in debugging mode) to the `write_lines()` function the program stops without any error.
Maybe someone has a clue what iam doing wrong

```
    public class Writer
{
    private StreamWriter the_writer;
    private string PS_filepath;

    public Writer()
    {

    }

    public void write_lines(List<string> thelines, string path)
    {
        this.PS_filepath = path;
        this.the_writer = new StreamWriter(PS_filepath, true);

        foreach(string line in thelines)
        {
            the_writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

`Path var is C:\path\text.xyz`

Comment: The function name should be WriteLines, not write_lines

Comment: What exactly does "the program stops without any error" mean? It's vague and makes it possible the error is something else completely.

Comment: @PeterRitchie it doesn't. I'm just pointing out that his function name isn't pascal case

Comment: Do you even have permissions to write to `C:\path\text.xyz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your writer is created locally but never properly closed.

There is no reason to store the variable in the instance and because of that the whole method can simply be made static:

```
public static void write_lines(List<string> thelines, string path)
{
    //this.PS_filepath = path;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
      foreach(string line in thelines)
      {
          writer.WriteLine(line);
      }
    }
}
```

The `using` will ensure your file is closed (and therefore written completely). The other changes are just small improvements.

Comment: i added `this.the_writer.Close();` didnt help

Comment: your code is working but at the moment i dont understand why mine didnt work. thanks alot